# What do Galiitzianers polish on Pesach "Shiny"?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

See [this Wikepedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yiddish_dialects) for an explanation on Yiddish dialects. Galitzianers pronounce "ey" as "ay".

Thus, the Galitzianers have a special holiday on the 16th of Iyar called "Pesach Shiny". I assume that being from Poland, they spend the day "polish" - ing stuff. What do they polish? I can't think of anything that takes a full day to polish.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

I once heard one of them giving a shiur about "*yesh koneh **ulamo bshoe** achas*". Now, for a shoe to be the same value as a wedding hall, it would have to be a very large shoe indeed, one that would take a very long time to polish. Perhaps that shoe is the item in question.

Comment: Y'know, even after many years of listening to my partially Galicianer grandpa (ob"m) speak, it took me a few minutes to figure out what YOU were saying. You're Galicianer??? If yes, I have no comment...